# md-divider after a tr using ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I would like the md-divider underline under each of my table rows. Especially since md-divider has the nice ng=if"!$last". But it seems like the ng-repeat has to go on the tr element so the divider couldn't go after the table row.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users" class="row">
    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
- I would want a divider here.
```

Note: I also tried just using a border and it doesnt even show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with css by giving border to `<td>` instead of `<tr>`

```
td{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000; // change color and size accordingly
}
```

> css border doesn't works in `<tr>` but you can apply it on `<td>` because both `<td>` in `<tr>` will have the same height so it will not create any problem.